# How to catch email already exists error on firebase 9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

hey there i have given 2 screenshots and i cannot catch the actual error message like "EMAIL_EXISTS"...i want to show it to the user but when i console log error.message its shows me the 1st screenshot..how can i achieve that with firebase 9...im using async await..heres my code

```
try {

  setLoading(true);
  const req = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  console.log(req)
  setLoading(false);
  dispatch({type: "SIGNUP", payload: req.user})
  dispatch({
    type: "visible",
    timer: 4000,
    message: "Signed Up Successfully! Login Now.",
    color: "SUCCESS",
  });
  dispatch({ type: "login" });
  return;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message)
  dispatch({
    type: "visible",
    timer: 3000,
    message: "Failed to Signup! Please try again",
    color: "ERROR",
  });
  setLoading(false);
  return;
}
```

[image][image]